# Show a bijection between two inverse images of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

$ \Phi: G \rightarrow H $ is a group homomorphism.

There are $ h,h' \in H $, so that $ \Phi^{-1}(\{h\})$ and $\Phi^{-1}(\{h'\})$ are not empty. Show a bijection between $ \Phi^{-1}(\{h\}) $ and $ \Phi^{-1}(\{h'\}) $

Do I need to create an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$? And if so, where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1) Let $g \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h\}), g' \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h'\})$. Note that $g, g'$ must exist because the inverse images of $h$ and $h'$ under $\Phi$ are nonempty.

2) Using the fact that $\Phi$ is a homomorphism, deduce that $\phi(g^{-1})=h^{-1}$.

3) Now show that for any $\alpha \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h\})$, $\Phi(\alpha g^{-1}g') = h$, i.e. $\alpha g^{-1}g \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h'\})$.

4) Finally, show that the map $\varphi: \Phi^{-1}(\{h\}) \rightarrow \Phi^{-1}(\{h'\})$ given by $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha g^{-1}g'$ is a bijection.